# Is it possible to hook Kotlin methods with Xposed framework?

Tags: android, kotlin-exposed, xposed

I have a android app and I need to hook and change function "func_one" via writing my own Xposed module. I'm using few scripts that bypass root detection in the same project, so I'd love to put that hook in the old project.
Is there's the way for Xposed to hook and change Kotlin method in the same project where I'm hooking Java methods?

I've tried to just hook it with the Xposed usual functionality, but it simply don't find func that I need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Kotlin code exists only at compile time (except from the kotlin runtime libraries that are included in the app). On Android app level everything is DEX code (or native arm64 code in a .so file). So yes, you can hook Kotlin methods. Simply decompile the APK e.g. using Jadx-Gui and you will see the method names and arguments.